# SSRS Deployed reports have disabled parameters in IE, and those without parameters just return a blank screen

Tags: sql-server, internet-explorer, reporting-services, report

I have a set of SSRS reports developed in Visual Studio Data Tools that are used for several clients.

For one particular site, each report will work perfectly in 'Preview' mode in Visual Studio, however when I deploy them and attempt to run them in IE all of the parameters are disabled/greyed out. I also tried to put in a set of default parameters to see what would happen and when I click 'Run Report' I do not even get the 'Loading' image and the report is just blank.

I have checked the IE security settings and have reset them, and also added the report web page location in to trusted sites which unfortunately hasn't made a difference. One thing I have also noticed is that when I try to view Developer Tools in IE, it also just shows a blank white screen.

I've searched online and found a couple of old posts on various websites with a similar issue but none that were ever resolved, and now I am not sure how to proceed.

More info that might be useful:
The client are using IE 11, it is a terminal server style setup with around 8 or 9 users logged on.
The report I am testing with has 2 date parameters first, and two multi-valued parameters (I have tried other reports but with the same issue)
The client recently moved servers and the reports worked fine before, although it was a fresh install of the report so I don't believe there would be any old settings that could be causing it?

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Which version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: They're on SQL Server 2012 Express, and the reports are developed in Visual Studio 2010 Data Tools

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior.  Setup is IE 11, SSRS 2014, and load balancer on https.  I get the url back fine, but the report never shows any loading spinner, and the report viewer body is empty.  My IE developer tools though are not blank, though I'm remoted onto the box.  Any help or insight into this from the community members would be awesome.

Comment: @Matt, Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: No sorry, I was looking at this on behalf of a customer I was doing some other work for but this issue was never resolved.

Answer (score 2):

In SSRS, report parameters can be inactive when the report is generated from a snapshot.  Removing this option is as follows:

1. Navigate to the report in SSRS
2. "Manage" the report from the drop down.
3. Select "Processing Options" from the left menu
4. Is "Render this report from a report snapshot" selected? If so, switch
   to "Always run this report with the most recent data" option.
5. Run the report to determine if parameters are now active.

If this fixes your issue, you may need to switch from the snapshot option to the Scheduled Cache option available under the left menu link "Cache Refresh Options"

Answer (score 2):

> For one particular site, each report will work perfectly in 'Preview' mode in Visual Studio, however when I deploy them and attempt to run them in IE all of the parameters are disabled/greyed out.

If that is the case, and a previous version of the report was already on the SSRS report server, what you can do is delete the report, and upload it again. There is some kind of cache for the parameters, that causes that if you modify the order of them, some get disabled, and the only way I have found to get rid of it is to delete the old report from the server.

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked:

- Open IE
- Go to Settings->Compatibility View Settings
- Add the URL of your report server.

Answer (score 1):

You could be experiencing an old bug which was reported a long time ago in a connect item:

- [SSRS Weird Parameters Order Bug (parameter grayed out)](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/490845/ssrs-weird-parameters-order-bug-parameter-grayed-out)

The official Microsoft answer on this subject is:

> Currently this behavior is per design. However we will consider this
>   behavior improvement in a future release of reporting services The
>   only workaround at this point is to change the order of the
>   parameters.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien, I've checked out that bug report and I think although similar my problem is not the same.  I do not have any default values for the report parameters and also unlike in their description, the report I have are running fine in design/preview mode - I only encounter the issue when viewing the deployed reports

Comment: @MattF - OK, leaving it here in case of somebody else with this issue. Have you tried viewing the reports in compatibility mode?

Comment: Yes I have tried compatibility mode but unfortunately still the same issue

Comment: @MattF - Have you looked at the report parameters configuration on the report server (`Manage` => `Parameters`)? To ensure the configuration is correct

Answer (score 0):

Are the parameters on the RDL file set to visible, like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just going to add this as an answer, because it solved the issue for me;
Delete the report on the server & deploy again.

What happens is that you completely remove the report and thus also its parameters. When you deploy a report its parameters their default values do not get overwritten in case it didn't have a default the first time you deployed.